# (Perl) Cannot do `initialize' in Term::ReadLine::Gnu in Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: macports, perl, readline

I recently installed MacPorts and I think it might have messed up some of my libraries. Now when I try to run the Perl debugger I get this:

```
>perl -d -e 0
Cannot do `initialize' in Term::ReadLine::Gnu at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/perl5db.pl line 6006
 at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm line 716
    Term::ReadLine::Gnu::AU::AUTOLOAD('Term::ReadLine=HASH(0x8f8b94)') called at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Term/ReadLine/Gnu.pm line 240
    Term::ReadLine::Gnu::new('Term::ReadLine', 'perldb', 'GLOB(0x85c690)', 'GLOB(0x855750)') called at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/perl5db.pl line 6006
    DB::setterm called at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/perl5db.pl line 2235
    DB::DB called at -e line 1
Cannot do `initialize' in Term::ReadLine::Gnu at /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/perl5db.pl line 6006
END failed--call queue aborted at -e line 44.
 at -e line 44
Config::DESTROY(/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level/Config.pm:63):
63: sub DESTROY { }
IO::Handle::DESTROY(/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level/IO/Handle.pm:330):
330:    sub DESTROY {}
```

I'm using readline 6.1. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install readline - Macports perl will look for the macports readline

Answer (score 0):

For the Mac, you would need to install to Perl from CPAN, the Term::ReadLine::Gnu module:

For example:  cpanm Term::ReadLine::Gnu

This fixed the problem for me.

Bob

Answer (score -1):

I executed

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies term-readline-gnu-perl
brew install term-readline-gnu-perl
```

and it worked.